# ModalPopupExtender to send parameters to the PopupControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i wanted to create a series of modalpopups to show help on certain fields on the form i have.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeMult" runat="server" TargetControlID="hlpMult" PopupControlID="Panel1" OkControlID="btnOkay"
                         drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"   >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

is it at all possible to pass in a parameter to `Panel1` and display text accordingly?

if i have to create different panels for each, i guess i'll have to find another way to do this.

or, maybe this could be done with `PopupControlExtender`?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the PopUp Extenders can be activated by javascript.  .show() I believe.  So you can have 1 javascript function that moves your help documentation into the right panel and then call show on the 1 extender which will display your newly moved text.